# Kotlin check if a variable is between two numbers

Tags: android, kotlin

**I have a current time from LocalTime.now(). I want to use this current time in check if between two double number But I can't convert the time to double**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val CurrentTime = LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH.mm"))

    tvDetailIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailIcon)
    testTime = view.findViewById(R.id.testTime)
    testTime.text = CurrentTime


    if (24.00<testTime && testTime<25.00 ){
        constraint.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#34495e"))
        tvDetailIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_nights_stay_24)
    }

    else if (1.00<testTime && testTime<24.00){
        constraint.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#349Bdb"))
        tvDetailIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_wb_sunny_72)

    }
```

[You can find fail here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mBkJ.png)

Comment: You should not start variable names with a capital letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly this `LocalTime > String > Float > Double` conversion seems really brittle, and I think you'd be better off creating some `LocalTime` instances representing the specific times you want to compare. Then you can use `LocalTime#isBefore` and `#isAfter` to do your comparisons.

There are even a few constants like `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` you can use. Plus `LocalTime`s use a limited range of values, from `MIN` to `MAX`, so you can avoid doing comparisons like `testTime < 25.00`

Comment: thank you for antwort.Its better than old code.

Answer (score 15):

The condition is to check whether it is between two numbers

```
val number = 5
val min = 2
val max = 10

if(number in min..max){
   Log.i("Yes, number is between min and max")
   } else{
     Log.i("No, number is not between min and max")
      }
```

Comment: Does this waste stack space if the range is large? Or is a range in kotlin some special type that only stores the min and max?
would `if (number > 0 && number < 100000000)`  be completely equivalent in performance to `if (number in 0..100000000)`?

Comment: @Olli May be careful, it is `(number >= 0 && number <= 100000000)`.  `<=`, `>=`

Comment: @Olli: see the code of IntRange (https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/e10e821cd47449ae2b0b4f83d34baacb84f176c6/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/ranges/PrimitiveRanges.kt#L66), it is:
override fun contains(value: Int): Boolean = first <= value && value <= last

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert currentTime to a Float and then use that in your compares.

```
val currentTimeAsFloat = CurrentTime.toFloat()
```

see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-float.html) String method